# Merge two Google Map codes

Tags: java, google-maps

I have followed this tutorial to enter a Lng/Lat and some form data on a google map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

I've got the code for inputing the form data using PHP and a custom form, and this is the problem.

The code for the marker entry is on a seperate HTML page to the code to present the SQL Results, how can I have the marker appear on the results page?